# Python - how to load Google Chrome or Chromium browser in the gtk.Window like webkit.WebView()?

Tags: python, linux, google-chrome, webkit, chromium

In Python (Linux), how can i load the Google chrome or Chromium browser inside a gtk.Window()?

Where i am using now as webkit but instead of the webkit i need to use Google Chrome/Chromium because of the Javscript engine and other update issues.

```
$ apt-get install python-webkit
$ cat >> /var/tmp/browser.py << \EOF
#!/usr/bin/env python
import gtk
import webkit
import gobject
gobject.threads_init()
win = gtk.Window()
win.set_title("Python Browser")
bro = webkit.WebView()
bro.open("http://www.google.com")
win.add(bro)
win.show_all()
gtk.main()

EOF
$ python /var/tmp/browser.py
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can embed Chrome ... you can create your application in Qt and embed QtWebkit ... or you can use selenium with whatever driver you wish including Chrome , but i don't think you can embed that .

Qtwebkit has all the features that you need.

EDIT

I take everything back because I just found something that might work. :D

https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/
"A simple framework for embedding chromium browser windows in other applications."

and this framework also has python bindings:
http://code.google.com/p/cefpython/

but i'm not sure if chromium has all the features that you need ...

Comment: But using QtWebKit we cant use latest JavaScript Engines + WebRTC + some more features available in Chrome/Chromium/Google Chrome.

Comment: Also using QtWebKit we cant use some features of Chrome such as: Google Hangout and many other modules.

Comment: Nope i haven't tested

Answer (score 5):

To extend sfantu answer. CEF Python comes with examples of embedding the Chrome browser in a PyGTK application, see the screenshot:

https://code.google.com/p/cefpython/wiki/PyGTK

Examples sources (CEF 1 / CEF 3 / Windows / Linux):

https://code.google.com/p/cefpython/source/browse/cefpython/cef1/windows/binaries/pygtk_.py 
https://code.google.com/p/cefpython/source/browse/cefpython/cef1/linux/binaries_64bit/pygtk_.py
https://code.google.com/p/cefpython/source/browse/cefpython/cef3/windows/binaries/pygtk_.py

Embedding the Chrome browser using CEF Python is possible using any framework you like (comes with examples for PyGTK, wxPython, PyQt, PySide, Panda3D, Kivy framework, PyWin32). You just pass a window handle to CEF and the browser is embedded in that window. On Linux it is required to pass a pointer to GtkWindow.

Comment: I have segmentation fault while running Linux 64-bit with python qt4 binding. e.g: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6158865/

Comment: @YumYumYum Please read the comment at the top of the pyqt.py file - this error is known. The pyqt example on Linux has been added only two days ago and has not yet been thoroughly tested. Further debugging is required to resolve this issue. The pyqt example works fine on Windows.

Comment: @YumYumYum You can copy the PyGTK CEF 3 example from Windows and it should run on Linux with some modifications, you would have to set the "locales_dir_path" and "resources_dir_path" options, see line 484 here: https://code.google.com/p/cefpython/source/browse/cefpython/cef3/linux/binaries_64bit/wxpython.py?r=2471b5fb1019#484 . Also change the "libcef.dll" at the beginning of the script with "libcef.so". Please create a topic on the CEF Python Forum if you encounter any problems with that.

Comment: @YumYumYum I've created [Issue 88](https://code.google.com/p/cefpython/issues/detail?id=88) for the pyqt error - star it and you will be notified by email when it gets fixed.

Answer (score 1):

According to [PyGTK FAQ](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=all#19.15), it's possible.

More info in [tutorial](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-PlugsAndSockets.html).

Answer (score 0):

use

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import platform
import os

name = "Google Chrome/Chromium"


def find_path():
    """
    find the chrome executable path on Windows, Linux/OpenBSD, Mac or Unknown system.
    """
    if platform.system() == "Windows":
        return _find_chrome_win()

    elif platform.system() == "Darwin":  # Mac OS
        return _find_chrome_mac()

    elif platform.system() == "Linux" or platform.system() == "OpenBSD":
        return _find_chrome_linux()

    else:
        try:
            return _find_chrome_linux()
        except:
            try:
                return _find_chrome_mac()
            except:
                try:
                    return _find_chrome_win()
                except:
                    return None


def _find_chrome_mac():
    paths = [  # mac os chrome path list
        "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome",
        "/Applications/Google Chrome Canary.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome Canary",
        "/Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium",
        "/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable",
        "/usr/bin/google-chrome",
        "/usr/bin/chromium",
        "/usr/bin/chromium-browser",
    ]

    chrome_path = None

    for path in paths:  # loop through paths
        if os.path.exists(path):
            chrome_path = path

    if chrome_path != None:
        return chrome_path

    else:  # use which command to find chrome
        for browser in ("google-chrome", "chrome", "chromium", "chromium-browser"):
            a = os.popen("which " + browser).read()
            if a == "":
                pass
            else:
                return a[:-1]

        return None


def _find_chrome_linux():
    paths = [
        "/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable",  # linux chrome path list
        "/usr/bin/google-chrome",
        "/usr/bin/chromium",
        "/usr/bin/chromium-browser",
        "/snap/bin/chromium",
    ]

    chrome_path = None

    for path in paths:
        if os.path.exists(path):
            chrome_path = path

    if chrome_path != None:
        return chrome_path

    else:  # use which command to find chrome
        for browser in ("google-chrome", "chrome", "chromium", "chromium-browser"):
            a = os.popen("which " + browser).read()
            if a == "":
                pass
            else:
                return a[:-1]

        return None


def _find_chrome_win():
    import winreg as reg  # import registry

    chrome_path = None
    reg_path = r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe"

    for install_type in (reg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, reg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE):
        try:
            reg_key = reg.OpenKey(install_type, reg_path, 0, reg.KEY_READ)
            chrome_path = reg.QueryValue(reg_key, None)
            reg_key.Close()
            if not os.path.isfile(chrome_path):
                continue
        except WindowsError:
            chrome_path = None
        else:
            break

    for browser in ("google-chrome", "chrome", "chromium", "chromium-browser"):
        a = os.popen("where " + browser).read()
        if a == "":
            pass
        else:
            chrome_path = a[:-1]

    return chrome_path


chrome_path = find_path()
if not chrome_path:
    raise Exception("No chrome")


class ChromeView:
    def __init__(self, url="data:text/html,<h1>DicksonUI</h1>", options=[]):
        cmd = chrome_path
        for option in options:
            cmd += " "
            cmd += option
        cmd += " --incognito"
        cmd += " --new-window"
        cmd += ' --app="'
        cmd += url + '"'
        os.popen(cmd)

    def version(self, path):
        try:
            v = os.popen(find_path() + " --version").read()
            v2 = v[v.find(" ") + 1 :]
            return int(v2[: v2.find(".")])
        except:
            return None

    def is_chromium(self, path):
        try:
            if os.popen(path + " --version").read().startswith("Chromium"):
                return True
            else:
                return False
        except:
            return None

ChromeView("https://www.google.com")
```