# how to Wrapping License Requests to drmtoday server via python

Tags: wrapper, licensing, mpeg-dash, drm, widevine

i'm trying to simulate drm media playing in python so i start with this demo from castlab "https://demo.castlabs.com/" and the video that i'm testing it is in MPEG-DASH format and drm system is widevine provided via cenc (if is that how to say it) , here is the url of the video

> https://demo.cf.castlabs.com/media/msspr/Manifest?v=5.1.38

key id is :

```
8bdf77c0-5665-46c5-8ec8-422e571fc000
```

and the pssh is :

```
AAAAVHBzc2gAAAAA7e+LqXnWSs6jyCfc1R0h7QAAADQIARIQi993wFZlRsWOyEIuVx/AABoIY2FzdGxhYnMiEIvfd8BWZUbFjshCLlcfwAAqAlNE
```

schemeIdUri (widevine) is :

```
edef8ba9-79d6-4ace-a3c8-27dcd51d21ed
```

and the drm server url :

> https://lic.staging.drmtoday.com/license-proxy-widevine/cenc/

the drm server need an custom header witch is :

```
dt-custom-data: eyJ1c2VySWQiOiJwdXJjaGFzZSIsInNlc3Npb25JZCI6InAwIiwibWVyY2hhbnQiOiJzaXgifQ==
```

and never change its base64 encoded from :

```
{"userId":"purchase","sessionId":"p0","merchant":"six"}
```

and it also need the body request or payload request , and thats where my problem is 
i was able to catch the body request in arraybuffer from chrom developer tool and converted to base64 an this is what i find

```
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
```

i really don't know how this code was formed i know that it converted to arraybuffer "Unit8 and "int8" and used as body request to the server , i coped this base64 code and try to decoded in this site "https://tools.axinom.com/decoders/LicenseRequest" and it give me information about the license request like Certificate and Serial Number and the signature plus the pssh data and content id , algorithm (AES-CTR)
now since most of the information that are stored in that base64 code are in my hand (pssh,kid,system id), i want to know how to create\build\wrapper the request in the same way that base64 code was build to use it in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request is generated by interacting with the CDM in the browser via the EME API: https://w3c.github.io/encrypted-media/. You can learn more by using this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eme-call-and-event-logger/cniohcjecdcdhgmlofniddfoeokbpbpb

Maybe this helps to call Chromium from Python: [Python - how to load Google Chrome or Chromium browser in the gtk.Window like webkit.WebView()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808809/python-how-to-load-google-chrome-or-chromium-browser-in-the-gtk-window-like-we/18987670)

You would also need to take care to enable Widevine in CEF, and there might be limitations associated with that because of some signature verification process. See
https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src/master/include/cef_web_plugin.h#lines-168
and look for "VMP" here: https://github.com/castlabs/electron-releases